# How to kill an Android app background process?

Tags: android, background-process, multiprocess

I have an app with two processes. The second process starts when an Activity is created. Find below an excerpt of that Activity in the Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityInAnotherProcess"
        android:process=":anotherprocess"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        ...
```

After the ":anotherprocess" starts I need to kill the main process somehow, through the adb, in code, however.

I've tried "Terminate Application" in the DDMS and the main process is killed but recreated after a few seconds.

I've tried this code:

```
String packageName = c.getPackageName();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

but the main process is killed only to be recreated after a few seconds.

**UPDATE:**
The code posted above works. I was calling it a few seconds after starting the Activity in the other process but it seems the other process was not fully started before I killed the main process. Now I'm killing the main process from the other process. This works now. Thanks all!

Comment: have you tried? android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: @dalmendray Why you want to kill the background process?

Comment: @Charuka I need to kill the main process to simulate when Android does it. I have interprocess communication in my code that I need to test based on the fact that the main process is killed (as it could be if Android needs more resources)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
    mActivityManager.restartPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
}
```

if API >= 8 use mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)

if API < 8  use mActivityManager.restartPackage(packageInfo.packageName);

Comment: Why doing the for loop if you already know the package name? Should be better to just call mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("mypackage")